# simple Regex question / multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex

Newbie Regex question / C#:

Consider (.*)=(.*) and how it would match "A = B = C"

I exepected to get two match objects back since there are two ways to group and match:

```
(A = B) = (C)   

     or 

(A) = (B = C)
```

However I get back only one match object (the first case).  So I guess I don't understand why the match collection is a collection - since I can't seem to get more than one item into it.  Can someone explain ?

---

fyi - for the above test I just used the immed window:

```
?Regex.Matches("A = B = C", "(.*)=(.*)").Count
 1

?Regex.Matches("A = B = C", "(.*)=(.*)")[0].Groups[1].Captures[0]
 Value: "A = B"

?Regex.Matches("A = B = C", "(.*)=(.*)")[0].Groups[1].Captures[1]
 Value: "C"
```

Comment: Actually, that regex won't match the (C) portion left.  Once the engine matches the first part, the remaining part left is... '= C', but your regex statement is asking for a letter then an equal then another letter.  I can't think of a regex that will do what you're looking for, but your regex is definitely not right for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection returned by `Matches` contains consecutive matches, not alternative matches for the same section of the string. So if you pass in a string like "A = B\nC = D", you'll get back two matches: one for "A = B" and one for "C = D" (as `.` does not match line breaks).

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` is normally greedy. This means it matches as many characters as possible whilst satisfying the expression. Therefore the first `.*` matches the "A = B", leaving the "C" for the second `.*`

You can change the behaviour using a ? after the expression. `.*?` will match as few characters as possible whilst satisfying the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions work in such a way that when a match is found, the part of the input that has been matched already is ignored from then on. So when `A = B` has been matched, that part of the input will not be subject to any more matching.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way....

If your input text was:

```
"A = B = C\r\nW = X = Z"
```

and your expression was

```
"([^=]?) = ([^=]?) = ([^=]?)"
```

then you would get multiple results. Please read documentation! :-D

Comment: Check out this: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ it is a good tool to design and edit Regex in C# and has built in help.

Answer (score 0):

The * quantifier is greedy. It makes the first expression `.*` matches many chars as possible, so, the expression will always match `(A = B) = (C).`

Using the not greedy quantifier `*?` will match `(A) = (B = C)`.

Try using it!